# Not able to translate gameObject when Animation is already added to it using Animator in Unity2D Sprite

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I am able to translate the gameObject from one point to other by the **OnMouseDrag()** Event have no problem in doing that. But when i have added Animation to the **GameObject** Using the Animator Im not able to handle its Dynamic translate property when the Drag event take place.

Details:-

1. The Animation that i have create for the Game object is that it gets Translate from the Outer side of the screen to a side of the screen, This happens on the launch of the scene. (This happens properly)
2. Now when i want to dynamically translate the game object on the mouse drag it doesn't translate. (if i have not added the animator to the object it translate with mouse drag with out an issue)

Can any Tell me why it is so ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your animation manipulates `transform.position` and is executed after the `OnMouseDrag` event has been raised, this appears correct so far. Maybe stopping the animation when the mouse button is clicked helps.

Comment: Kay: The problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making Gameobject with animation,a child of an empty Gameobject and then translating that parent gameobject.